# RestSharp - could not be found

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have looked at other questions posted about this but nothing seems to answer my question/problem.   Hopefully because my question/problem seems like a simple fix if anything.

I installed RestSharp using nuget.

```
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;
```

are underlined with blue

```
private IRestClient restClient;
```

is also underlined.

If i restart my IDE, there is no error. I hit build to compile my object.. and all the RestSharp references "disappear."  I try to add the reference manually using the RestSharp.dll and it barks at me telling me that there is already a reference to RestSharp

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Looks like version conflict between .net framework and version of RestSharp or your project is configured under .net client profile.

Comment: ya i just realized I marked the project as 3.5.. RestSharp is 4 or greater..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the Framework from anything less than 4 up to 4 and recompile.

restsharp was developed and compiled in 4.0

Answer (score 0):

had same error. it did compiled in 4.7 version. what i did is created folders where vs looking the dll file, and put the dll in there.